# Series with 1d array to 2d numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Series containing 1D arrays/lists. I want to extract it to a 2D NumPy array.

```py
s=pd.Series([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

With `to_numpy()` I get a 1D array looking like this

```py
array([list([1, 2, 3, 4]), list([5, 6, 7, 8])], dtype=object)
```

However, I want something like `array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert first to `list`s and then to array:

```
arr = np.array(s.tolist())
print (arr)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

Comment: Hello meanwhile i have found a solution anyways:) i used np.array([*s.array])